# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /teacher/class_students_list

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Views.py

```
#For Student Registration 
def StudentSignUp(request):
    user_type = 'Student'
    registered= False

    if request.method == "POST":
        logger_Form = loggerform(data = request.POST)
        Student_Form = StudentForm(data = request.POST)
        if logger_Form.is_valid() and Student_Form.is_valid():

            user = logger_Form.save()
            user.is_student = True
            user.save()

            profile = Student_Form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()

            registered = True
        else:
            print(logger_Form.errors,Student_Form.errors)
    else:
        logger_Form = loggerform()
        Student_Form = StudentForm()
    return render(request,'student_signup.html',{'logger_Form':loggerform,'Student_Form':StudentForm,'registered':registered,'user_type':user_type})

# FOR teacher Registration 
def TeacherSignUp(request):
    user_type = 'Teacher'
    registered = False 

    if request.method == "POST":
        logger_Form = loggerform(data = request.POST)
        Teacher_Form = TeacherForm(data = request.POST)

        if logger_Form.is_valid() and Teacher_Form.is_valid():

            user = logger_Form.save()
            user.is_teacher = True
            user.save()

            profile = Teacher_Form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()

            registered = True
        else:
            print(logger_Form.errors,Teacher_Form.errors)
    else:
        logger_Form = loggerform()
        Teacher_Form = TeacherForm()
    return render(request,'teach_signup.html',{'logger_Form':loggerform,'Teacher_Form':TeacherForm,'registered':registered,'user_type':user_type})


#List of all the students that teacher has added in their class
def class_students_list(request):
    query = request.GET.get("q", None)
    students = StudentsInClass.objects.filter(teacher = request.user.Teacher)
    students_list = [x.student for x in students]
    qs = Student.objects.all()
    if query is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(
                Q(name__icontains=query)
                )
    qs_one = []
    for x in qs:
        if x in students_list:
            qs_one.append(x)
        else:
            pass
    context = {
        "class_students_list": qs_one,
    }
    template = "class_students_list.html"
    return render(request, template, context)

class ClassStudentsListView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = models.Teacher
    template_name = "class_students_list.html"
    context_object_name = "teacher"
```

Models.py

```
class logger(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Student(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(logger,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,related_name='Student')
    name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    roll_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['roll_no']

class Teacher(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(logger,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,related_name='Teacher')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    class_students = models.ManyToManyField(Student,through="StudentsInClass")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('teacher_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class StudentsInClass(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher,related_name="class_teacher",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student,related_name="user_student_name",on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student.name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('teacher','student')
```

forms.py

```
# User Login Form common for both student and teacher login
class loggerform(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta():
        model = logger
        fields = ['username','password1','password2']
        widgets = {
                'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'answer'}),
                'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'answer'}),
                'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'answer'}),
                }

# Teacher SignUp Form 
class TeacherForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model =  Teacher
        fields = ['name','subject_name','email']
        widgets = {
                'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'answer'}),
                'subject_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'answer'}),
                'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'answer'}),
                }

# Student SignUp Form
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model =  Student
        fields = ['name','roll_no','email']
        widgets = {
                'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'answer'}),
                'roll_no': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'answer'}),
                'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'answer'}),
                }
```

class_students_list.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<div class="student-list">
<div class="container">
  {% if class_students_list.count == 0 %}
    <h1>No students in the class.</h1>
    {% else %}

  <form method='GET' action="{% url 'class_student_list' %}">
    <p>Search Student: <input type='search' name='q' placeholder='Search'></p>
  </form>
  <div class="row">
  {% for student in class_students_list %}
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="student-box">
    <div class="imgBx">
      {% if student.student_profile_pic %}
      {% else %}
      {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"2" %}
      {% else %}
      {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h3>{{ student.name }}</h3>
      <p><i class="far fa-user"></i> Username: {{ student.user.username }}</p>
      <p><i class="fal fa-user-tag"></i> Roll No.: {{ student.roll_no }}</p>
      <p><i class="far fa-phone"></i> Phone: {{ student.phone }}</p>
      <p><i class="far fa-envelope-open-text"></i> Email ID: {{ student.email }}</p>
      <a href="#"><p class="add-button">View Marks Profile</p></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

This is the Traceback that I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/vinayak/Desktop/CS IA /src/IB_Portal/Portal/views.py", line 125, in class_students_list
    students = StudentsInClass.objects.filter(teacher = request.user.Teacher)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 241, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 421, in __get__
    raise self.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist(
Portal.models.logger.Teacher.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: logger has no Teacher.
[28/Feb/2021 10:02:23] "GET /teacher/class_students_list HTTP/1.1" 500 67048
```

I have posted my code, above I dont know why I keep getting the error in the title, I can't seem to figure it out, can anyone please help me out, I'm still in school and new to django. Any sort of help would be appreciated. Anyone who can solve the problem, please post the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Are non-teacher users supposed to access the view `class_students_list`?

Comment: no, the non-teacher users cannot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly in your Sign up views you write `profile.user = user` whereas in your models this field is named `username`. Change this line to either `profile.username = user` or change the name of the field. I would suggest the field's name as it doesn't make sense currently.

Since users that are not teachers are not supposed to access the view you should also add that restriction to your view (you might get the error because you access the view by a non-teacher user). A simple way to do that would be to use the `user_passes_test` decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test


def user_is_teacher(user):
    return user.is_authenticated and user.is_teacher

@user_passes_test(user_is_teacher)
def class_students_list(request):
    ...
```

Next your filtering of the students is somewhat too complicated. It can be done in a simpler way with the ORM. And if you use a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) it would be even easier. You can add this on either your `Student` model or your `Teacher` model. Since from looking at your code the `Teacher` model is defined later we would add the many to many field to it. Considering you already have a model that makes this relationship we will keep it as the `through` model:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    # Your other fields
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name="teachers", through="StudentsInClass")
```

Now in your view:

```
@user_passes_test(user_is_teacher)
def class_students_list(request):
    query = request.GET.get("q", None)
    students = request.user.Teacher.students.all()
    if query is not None:
        students = students.filter(Q(name__icontains=query))
    context = {
        "class_students_list": students,
    }
    template = "class_students_list.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: Hi, I tired the way you posted but I'm still getting the same error at

Comment: students = request.user.Teacher.students.all()

Comment: It says logger has no Teacher

Comment: @Codesvink I had edited the answer a little. Check the start of the answer. Your sign up views were incorrect. The users you have made up till now have no teacher / user object.

Comment: @Codesvink My bad I was mistaken there (you went against naming conventions). As a note in python code always name variables (and functions) in `snake_case` and classes in `PascalCase` your code breaks this convention in multiple places (These conventions convey a lot of information about a variable to people).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, as it turns out, all the teacher accounts that I created were simple users not specified  as either teacher or student.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'll try and take care of the conventions